# Convert String to UUID formatted string

Tags: java, string, formatting, uuid, utility

Is there any utility method available to convert plain string to UUID formatted string?

For example:

**Plain String:** f424376fe38e496eb77d7841d915b074

**UUID formatted String:** f424376f-e38e-496e-b77d-7841d915b074

I just wanted to convert to UUID format without using any java logic, hence looking for predefined utility available in java.lang, java.util or Apache, etc packages.

Comment: What about inserting dashes?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can simply use `String.format` in the following way:

```
String plain = "f424376fe38e496eb77d7841d915b074";
String uuid = String.format("%1$-%2$-%3$-%4$", plain.substring(0,7), plain.substring(7,11), plain.substring(11,15), plain.substring(15,20));
```

Or with more library methods using Apache Commons Codec (org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex class) and JDK (java.util.UUID class):

```
byte[] data = Hex.decodeHex("f424376fe38e496eb77d7841d915b074".toCharArray());
String uuid = new UUID(ByteBuffer.wrap(data, 0, 8).getLong(), ByteBuffer.wrap(data, 8, 8).getLong()).toString();
```